# Better way to write nested exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, try-except

```
    try:
        return load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        try:
            return load(otherfile)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None
```

How to write it more clean ? I feel there must be a better way to acomplish this (I assume there will be third file to load when other two will fail)

Comment: `for f in file_list: try: return load(f) except ...`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it into the loop if you will have many files:

```py
file_list = [file, otherfile]
for f in file_list:
    try:
        return load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue
return None
```